# fetching Object value without using map, forEach, for....in function in javascript/ node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`marine`,
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
     }
    ]
    
    console.log(object[name]);
```

How to access all name without using map function forEach function for...in

- I tried to by writing `console.log(object[1]);` but its not helping me

any other method and easy method to access only specific key value from Object? as i don't want to use ForEach, map for...in function just simple way to print name

Comment: is it only map that you cannot use? Or all iterators (foreach, for in, for of, reduce, etc)

Comment: `console.log(object[1].name)`

Comment: map forEach for in just need simplest way to find console name @Kinglish

Comment: @Vikas - Please clarify in question description itself that what can you use and what you cannot.

Comment: If you can't use any kind of iteration, then the only thing you can do is array indexing like you show. You can put the index in a variable first, but that's it. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: why you cannot use map, foreach or for? your object is an array, you have to access each element of an array by index

Comment: console.log( object.find(element => element.name == 'animal'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method using `while()`

```
let names=[], x =-1
while(++x<object.length) names.push(object[x].name);
```

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`marine`,
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
     }
    ]
    
    let names=[], x =-1
    while(++x<object.length) names.push(object[x].name);
    console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex?

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`marine`,
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
     }
    ]
    
const matches = [...JSON.stringify(object)
  .matchAll(/"name":"(\w+)"/g)]
  .map(match => match[1]);

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Until someone actually uses it, because they found it on SO… 